# Otherwise actions AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I'm changing my home background onClick in a function like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('HeaderCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.onProfile = function(){
    tools.displayBackground5('');
    };
  });
```

and like this :

```
window.tools = {
    displayBackground5 : function (type)
    {
        $("#first-part").removeClass('first-part');
        $("#first-part").removeClass('second-background');
        $("#first-part").removeClass('third-background');
        $("#first-part").removeClass('fourth-background');
    }
}
```

The problem is when I'm going back or when I'm using a bad url the removed classes are not setting back.

Is it possible to add a  default class for my "otherwise" ?

I hope to be clear enought.

thanks,

Nam's

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `ng-class` to toggle the classes?

Comment: yes there is a reason, I want to change a class from my header.html on a button click from my view. This is my indeex.html                                                                                             <div ng-include="'views/partials/header.html'"></div>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <div ng-include="'views/partials/footer.html'"></div>

Comment: Then I would consider using `$rootscope` this would allow you to use `ng-class`

Comment: Thanks @Malkus but my two element are not in the same controler, could you give me an exemple ?

Comment: `$rootScope` is shared across the whole application.  So if you set a `$rootScope` value it would be available anywhere in your app.  You shouldn't overuse it but for what you are doing it makes sense.

Comment: Could you show me how to use it ?